# linux kernel image strings extraction

Tags: linux-kernel, binary, executable, c-strings

I'm trying to extract the strings from a binary linux kernel image
(this specific phenomena happens in all types of images I've tried: bzImage, vmlinuz, vmlinux, .... and not a specific one)

Simply running 'strings ' prints many strings with a prefix character, for example:
"**4**netlink: %d bytes leftover after parsing attributes in process `%s'."

However, looking at the kernel sources, the current string should not include the "4" prefix.
While opening the file using some HEX editor, I've seen that the string actually also includes:
'\x00\x01' and only then '\x34' ("4")
My guess is this is some kind of pointer to a special section, or something of the sorts,
because many other strings include "3" and other numbers (and even characters).

Would appreciate any information in the matter
Thanks!

Comment: The `4` comes from the `KERN_WARNING` prefix. The `3` comes from the `KERN_ERR` prefix. Etc.

Comment: In any case, `strings` use heuristics to find strings. You may find other data concatenated (\0-terminated strings are common in C, but kernel has often fix delimited strings (when protocol prescript the length, and \0 may be significant). So use `strings` only as approximate tool (and never blindly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefixes OP is seeing are KERN_<LEVEL> prefixes. These are special string literals to be added before the main `printk` format specifier, using C's concatenation of adjacent string literals. For example:

```
    printk(KERN_ERR "Something has gone wrong!\n");
```

From kernel version 3.6 onwards, these KERN_<LEVEL> prefix macros are defined in "include/linux/kern_levels.h" and begin with the ASCII SOH character `"\001"` followed by the log level as an ASCII digit for the numeric levels, or some other ASCII character for special meanings.  The string for `KERN_DEFAULT` changed from `"\001" "d"` to `""` (empty string) in kernel version 5.1.  The string for `KERN_CONT` changed from `""` (empty string) to `"\001" "c"` in kernel version 4.9.

From kernel version 2.6.37 to 3.5.x, the KERN_<LEVEL> prefix macros were defined in "include/linux/printk.h" and used a different format with the level specified between angle brackets, for example `KERN_WARNING` was defined as `"<4>"`, `KERN_DEFAULT` was defined as `"<d>"`, and `KERN_CONT` was defined as `"<c>"`.

Besides `printk`, there are other macros for generating kernel logs, some of which specify the KERN_<LEVEL> part implicitly. OP's example from "lib/nlattr.c":

```
        pr_warn_ratelimited("netlink: %d bytes leftover after parsing attributes in process `%s'.\n",
                    rem, current->comm);
```

Here, the `pr_warn_ratelimited` macro is defined in "include/linux/printk.h" as:

```
#define pr_warn_ratelimited(fmt, ...)                   \
    printk_ratelimited(KERN_WARNING pr_fmt(fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

There is a lot going on there, but `pr_fmt(fmt)` is one or more string literals including `fmt` macro parameter, so the string passed to `printk_ratelimited` is constructed from some concatenated string literals beginning with those from the expansion of `KERN_WARNING`.